# Python regex to remove specific pattern from a list of strings

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a list of strings with filenames. The filenames follow a specific naming format:

```
string1_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_string2
```

Here YYYYMMDD and HHMMSS are actual date and time values.

I want to delete all characters that appear after 'string1' for each of the entries. I've been trying this with regex but to no vain. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a regex, just split on the first underscore:

```
s = 'string1_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_string2'
return s.split('_')[0]
```

[edit]:

If you can only rely on the last parts ('_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_string2') then try indexing like this:

```
s = 's_t_r_i_n_g_1_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_string2'
return '_'.join(s.split('_')[:-3])
```

Comment: Short & Sweet !!!

Comment: I could have done that but the 'string1' may contain underscores as well. The only pattern that always repeats at the end of each string is _YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_string2

Comment: Well Thanks @HumanCatfood !

Comment: I wouldn't have to use regex as per this solution

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Answer (score 2):

Using regex:

```
import re
s = 'string1_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_string2'
newstr = re.sub('_.*', '', s)
print(newstr)
```

Notes:

- `_.*` matches with a `_` and all of its following characters.
- `re.sub(p, r, s)` searches `s` for `p` and replaces all matches with `r`.

---

**Update #1**

> string1 may contain additional underscores. I'd like to retain all of string1 and only get rid of the trailing pattern.

In this case you can use the following regex:

```
_\d{8}_\d{6}_.*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jS2gL5/1

Comment: string1 may contain additional underscores. I'd like to retain all of string1 and only get rid of the trailing pattern.

Comment: @SudeepMohanty See the update!

Comment: Your latest update does the job as well! Thanks!